# JQuery Load Page into Div ... How to access external div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading a page into a div like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://mysite/form1.php" />');


    $( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) {
      alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
      event.preventDefault();
      });


  });
</script>
```

I can see with firefox that the page loaded is on a frame.

My question is, how can I access anything on the loaded page with jquery ?

Comment: possible duplicate of : how to access iframe elements with jquery

Comment: It's loading in a div ... object data="...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using jQuery .load() to do the same thing but only return the element that you need and not withing a frame. [Jquery .load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)  But to answer your question try using the .contents() to get the information you need. [jQuery .contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

```
$('#siteloader').load("mysite/form1.php")
.success(function(){ 
   $( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) { 
     alert( "Handler for .submit() called." ); 
     event.preventDefault(); 
   }); 
})
```

EDIT: added code

Comment: What I exactly want to do is to use jquery onsubmit event as there's a form on the page I'm loading

Comment: ok so what I would do is use the .load to load the form and than with the .success callback drop in your onSubmit code, Once the page is rendered using the .load() you can apply whatever jQuery code you want. Something to this effect.
         
    .load("mysite/form1.php")
.success(function(){
$( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) {
      alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
      event.preventDefault();
      });
})

Comment: I understand what you mean but what I'm I targeting? For example: $( "#whatAmI" ).load( ...  ... What do I replace the "whatAmI" with?

Comment: The element where you want your form loaded. $('#siteloader') using the  example you gave.